# compile errors in Java tutorial

Tags: java, compilation

```
public class HelloWorldSWT {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("Hello world!");
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}

}
```

output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Display cannot be resolved to a type
    Display cannot be resolved to a type
    Shell cannot be resolved to a type
    Shell cannot be resolved to a type

    at HelloWorldSWT.main(HelloWorldSWT.java:10)
```

I am new to Java, I have tried these but still not working:

Instruction told me: You will get compile errors. Right click in the Java editor and select Source > Organize Imports, then save your changes.

Comment: Where is your Display class? You need to add import statement.

Comment: Did you do as the instructions said and "Right click in the Java editor and select Source > Organize Imports, then save your changes"?  Also, you need to make sure the appropriate jars are in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

First, you will have to add appropriate library to your project (***swt-gtk-x.y.jar*** in your case).

Your IDE will have the possibility to figure proper imports for you then.